# sort by second string in database field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below sql statement which sorts an address field (address1) using the street name not the number.  This seems to work fine but I want the street names to appear alphabetically.  The ASC at the end of order by doesnt help
e.g Address1 field might contain 
"5 Elm Close"  - a normal sort and order will sort by the number the below will sort by looking at the 2nd string "Elm"
(Using SQL Server)

```
SELECT tblcontact.ContactID, tblcontact.Forename, tblcontact.Surname, 
tbladdress.AddressLine1, tbladdress.AddressLine2 
FROM tblcontact 
INNER JOIN tbladdress 
  ON tblcontact.AddressID = tbladdress.AddressID 
LEFT JOIN tblDonate 
  ON tblcontact.ContactID = tblDonate.ContactID 
WHERE (tbladdress.CollectionArea = 'Queens Park')
GROUP BY tblcontact.ContactID, tblcontact.Forename, tblcontact.Surname, 
tbladdress.AddressLine1, tbladdress.AddressLine2
ORDER BY REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(tbladdress.AddressLine1), 
            charindex(' ', REVERSE(tbladdress.AddressLine1)+' ')-1)) asc
```

Gordon's statement sorts as below

```
1 Kings Road
10 Olivier Way
11 Albert Street
11 Kings Road
11 Princes Road
120 High Street
```

Comment: What about `Penthouse, 123 Elm close` or `123 "Dunroamin", Elm close` or `The old Priory Elm Close` and other permutations? Why not store house name, house number and street separately?

Comment: I think I may have to do that, I should have been more forward thinking in my db design!  but currently all my addresses are "number + street name" I can at least continue with a first release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: I based it off of Gordon's code, but altered it to remove the `LEFT(AddressLine1, 1`) portion - a single-character string could never be match the pattern "*n* + *space* + %".

This works on my SQL-Server 2012 environment:

```
WITH tbladdress AS 
  (
    SELECT AddressLine1 FROM (VALUES ('1 Kings Road'),('10 Olivier Way'), ('11 Albert Street')) AS V(AddressLine1)
  )

SELECT 
    AddressLine1
FROM tbladdress 
order by (case when tbladdress.AddressLine1 like '[0-9]% %'
               then substrING(tbladdress.AddressLine1, charindex(' ', tbladdress.AddressLine1) + 1, len(tbladdress.AddressLine1))
               else tbladdress.AddressLine1
          end)
```

This is edited to be more similar to Gordon's code (position of closing parentheses, `substr` instead of `substring`):

```
order by (case when tbladdress.AddressLine1 like '[0-9]% %'
               then substr(tbladdress.AddressLine1, charindex(' ', tbladdress.AddressLine1) + 1), len(tbladdress.AddressLine1)
               else tbladdress.AddressLine1
          end)
```

Comment: thanks this seems to work - I'm getting multiple rows which are the same the distinct command gives me the above error hence the reason for the "group by" which is not working now

Comment: Add the `CASE` statement to your SELECT, and use `SELECT DISTINCT`

Comment: just checked I had duplicate records seems to be working great thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that the street name is the first or second value in a space separated string, you could try:

```
order by (case when left(tbladdress.AddressLine1, 1) like '[0-9]% %'
               then substr(tbladdress.AddressLine1, charindex(' ', tbladdress.AddressLine1) + 1), len(tbladdress.AddressLine1) )
               else tbladdress.AddressLine1
          end)
```

Comment: doesnt quite work pretty much gives the same result as the original 
see above for output

Comment: The one by AHiggins sorts alphabetically

Comment: This doesn't order alphabetically?  The code looks pretty similar to me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to use `REVERSE()` at all.  That seems like a trap.

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(LEFT(tbladdress.AddressLine1,CHARINDEX(' ',tbladdress.AddressLine1) - 1))
        THEN RIGHT(tbladdress.AddressLine1,LEN(tbladdress.AddressLine1) - CHARINDEX(' ',tbladdress.AddressLine1))
        ELSE tbladdress.AddressLine1
    END,
    CASE 
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(LEFT(tbladdress.AddressLine1,CHARINDEX(' ',tbladdress.AddressLine1) - 1))
        THEN CAST(LEFT(tbladdress.AddressLine1,CHARINDEX(' ',tbladdress.AddressLine1) - 1) AS INT)
        ELSE NULL
    END
```

Also, you have a `GROUP BY` with no aggregate function.  While that's not wrong, per se, it is weird.  Just use `DISTINCT` if you're getting duplicate records.

Comment: I'm using the group by because when I use distinct I get the error ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.  But "Group By" doesnt seem to work now

Comment: @AShah Well, the way to handle that is to simply place your all the fields in your `ORDER BY` after your real sorting fields.  That way they satisfy the `DISTINCT` requirements, but they're also all lower sorting priority than everything else.  Adding `tblcontact.Surname, tblcontact.Forename, tbladdress.AddressLine2, tblcontact.ContactID` to your `ORDER BY` should work.  If it still complains, add `tbladdress.AddressLine1` at the very end.

Answer (score 0):

This is the bit of code that works in sql server

```
order by (case when tbladdress.AddressLine1 like '[0-9]% %'
then substrING(tbladdress.AddressLine1, charindex(' ', tbladdress.AddressLine1) + 1, len(tbladdress.AddressLine1))
else tbladdress.AddressLine1
end)
```